# Can I move linuxbrew folder to another machine?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, homebrew, linuxbrew

I installed `homebrew` on my Ubuntu machine and installed `gcc` with it. Than I copied `/home/linuxbrew` folder to another machine into `/home/my_program/tools` directory. When I try to run `gcc` from that folder I get the `No such file or directory` error:

```
sm@sm:~/my_program$ ./tools/ubuntu/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc
bash: ./tools/ubuntu/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
```

but the file is there.

Then I ran `ldd` on it and I got this:

```
sm@sm:~/my_program$ ldd ./tools/ubuntu/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd7a387000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f31458e6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3145600000)
    /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f31459de000)
```

I guess the problem might be with the absolute path to `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ld.so`. I tried preloading `ld.so` from `my_program` directory using `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, but then I got the `Floating point exception (core dumped)`:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/home/sm/my_program/tools/ubuntu/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/2.35_1/bin/ld.so; ldd ./tools/ubuntu/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Any ideas what might be the problem? Is this even possible what I am trying to achieve (ie. not install `homebrew` on another machine, but use `gcc` that was installed with `homebrew` on the first machine)?